# interaction between python script and user in text mode

Tags: python

I am seeking for a good example or manual describing standards of text-based dialogs in a linux console using standard I/O commands and utilizing formatted text output. For example: how to inquire input of parameters proposing some default values and alternatives, how to do a progress bar in the text mode, and other stuff which looks very cool in bash scripts.

Comment: You mean command-line tool? If so Try docopt from docopt.org and progress bar ah I forgot the plugin. For command-line as basic as raw_input and a bunch of if/else, or the use of argparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"text-based dialogs in a linux console" --> have a look at [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html)